# How to add interactivity to Google Chart in ASP.NET with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

This is my first time to use Google Charts with ASP.NET and C#. I am struggling right now with adding an interactivity to the chart. What I want to do is the following; when the user clicks on any part of the pie chart, he will be redirected to another page in a new browser window that shows the list of items belonging to that part.

I have the following pie chart that shows three parts; positive, neutral and negative. I want when the user clicks on, for example, positive part, he gets redirected to another page in a new browser windows with passing to values to the URL; part value (positive) and id from the url of page that contains the chart itself. **So how can I do that?**
[image]

I was able so far to add an event (select event) to the chart and when the user clicks on any part, a popup window will be displayed as shown below. The chart is on a page with a url:

> http://localhost:49953/Test/TestPage3/5

And the user should be redirected to another page with passing two values; positive and 5:

> http://localhost:49953/Test/TestPage4/5#positive

[image]

Here's the code for the chart's listener part:

```
//add event to the chart
            function selectHandler() {
                var selectedItem = pieChart.getSelection()[0];
                if (selectedItem) {
                    var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                    alert('The user selected ' + topping);
                }
            }
            google.visualization.events.addListener(pieChart, 'select', selectHandler);
```